# Tortoise-orm raise KeyError in High Concurrency

Tags: python, mysql, tortoise-orm

I use Tortoise-orm in FastAPI, Mysql connection pool settings is `{"minsize":8, "maxsize":16}`。

```py
# models.py
class Device(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    model = fields.CharField(max_length=32)
    version = fields.CharField(max_length=32)
        port = fields.IntField(default=0)
    
class Channel(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    Device = fields.ForeignKeyField("model.Device", related_name="channels")
    frequency = fields.IntField(default=0, index=True)


#routers.py
@app.get("channels/{port}", response_model=ChannelSchema)
async def get_channels(port:int)
        return await ChannelSchema.from_queryset(Channel.filter(Device__port=port))
```

I tested this API using JMeter:

The first time is 100 interface requests per second：50% of requests is 500 error，

Viewing service logs:

```
  File "/root/TuffyProjects/simulator/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 742, in _init_from_db

KeyError: 'model'
```

or

```
File "/root/TuffyProjects/simulator/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 742, in _init_from_db

KeyError: 'frequency'
```

The second time is 100 interface requests per second：20% of requests is 500 error.

The third time is 100 interface requests per second：5% of requests is 500 error.

The fourth time is 100 interface requests per second：5% of requests is 500 error.

When I increased the number of concurrent requests, the number of errors went back up to 50%.

I will restart the service and re-test it.

The first time is 100 interface requests per second：50% of requests is 500 error，A look at the server logs shows that the KeyError prompt is not `model`or `frequency` but two other fields.

I changed the connection pool settings to `minsize":100, "maxsize":100}`, Mysql log prompt when starting project:

```
2022-03-09T07:09:24.855819Z 116 [Note] Aborted connection 116 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-03-09T07:09:24.855712Z 78 [Note] Aborted connection 78 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-03-09T07:09:24.855140Z 124 [Note] Aborted connection 124 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-03-09T07:09:24.856009Z 123 [Note] Aborted connection 123 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-03-09T07:09:34.903747Z 108 [Note] Aborted connection 108 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-03-09T07:09:34.903765Z 104 [Note] Aborted connection 104 to db: 'Device' user: 'root' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

But the service runs normally and the number of concurrent requests errors is reduced.

What is the cause of this BUG? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Look at your MySQL logs too?

Comment: I later found it was due to my use of `asyncio.open_connection` in the tortoise transaction `with` block, ty!